# SWT TreeViewer, trim string text in columns

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, treeviewer

I'm using a SWT `TreeViewer` to show some paths, is it possible to trim the path string to insert "..." (points) when the path is too long a is not fully visible in the tree column?

Something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's done manually in Error Log View (http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/pde/internal/runtime/logview/LogViewLabelProvider.java.htm) at least.

Comment: This is a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=137772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, reading the TreeColumn code I have noticed that the TreeViewer add ellipsis (...) to the columns automatically, but only if the column index is > 0. So column 0 strings are not truncated.

Try all eclipse views that uses a TreeView.

Really I don't understand this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`DecoratingLabelProvider`](http://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/DecoratingLabelProvider.html) over the `LabelProvider` which shows full paths (which is presumably what you have at the moment).

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what I'm looking for. I think that I'm looking an flag or setting in the TreeViewer that do this automatically. See my edits.